# Кодировка русских букв в HTML, получаемых через URL

Tags: java, android, html, url, httpurlconnection

После отработки кода, полученные данные записываются в базу данных, но ввиде ���������. Как указать кодировку?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://pomni.info/pomni/home/view/kaloriinosti_productov.html");
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
                    String inputLine;
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("<td>(\\D+)<\\/td>");
                    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        Matcher m = pattern1.matcher(inputLine);
                        if (m.find()) {
                            System.out.println(m.group(1));
                            contentValues.put(SQLHelper.KEY_PRODUCT, m.group(1));
                            sqlHelper.insertProduct(contentValues);
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: в бд поставьте на поле кодировку utf-8

Comment: Даже в систем аут приходят вопросы.

Comment: А что в ответе сервера в заголовке?

Answer (score 1):

В заголовках с сервера ничего, но согласно тэгам самой страницы это `windows-1251`

```
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Соответственно, если пытаться читать это как `UTF-8`, будут одни ромбики :)